# Qml MenuItem with Comma in Shortcut

Tags: qt, qml, keyboard-shortcuts, menubar

I am writing a Qt 6.5 Qml application with a menubar. It should have "Ctrl+," as a shortcut, but the QML shortcuts are comma delimited. How can I escape the comma to define the shortcut?

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import Qt.labs.platform

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Example Window")

    MenuBar {
        id: menuBar
        Menu {
            id: mnu
            title: qsTr("Menu")
           
            MenuItem // Next
            {
                id: nextItem
                shortcut: "Ctrl+,"
                text: qsTr("Next")
            }
            MenuItem // Previous
            {
                id: prevItem
                shortcut: "Ctrl+."
                text: qsTr("Previous")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Qt.Key_Comma instead of ","?

Comment: @JarMan I would but assigning the shortcut only to with `shortcut: Qt.Key_Comma` results in a display shortcut equivalent to "Shift+RightArrow" and no combination of `Key_Comma` and `Ctrl` seem to work.

Comment: I tried it with QtQuick.Controls and "Ctrl+," worked just fine for me. Try it [here](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMOAUKJLIsmlngOrAB2AJhAO66ElnTxKoaY8AYQgMYUCABsAzhyLFiAQTBhJGAIYxgo+szZwA3sTgm4wJgC44rRi1bHTNpjAAWVgGwAWAAwOTLgFNgAHMXGCtPAA5fUzgAN2BpYAAjSQCrcRQAvzgtGDSrAEdpABUoAAoAIgBRAA91cDS4XTtKgEoFWJAAhhQAIXUoKwBZHv7BwxzY0d7J2PnTPIK4YrKqgDIAMWA09qmFuEV0LVFDXIDa8JXSisqAJQCmdrh9g9NpFx50FCvKoXFJABqaSVV5vOCiMohYIBKCPKw2PSsPDoKTQOAAXjglThTzBsQAvvjTDMUABlAJgQaadEGOBE8GmI4nBhnYkLGAXK6rW59SRZZ7s+YfL4-Kx-AGAgA0oMZC0hUGhsPh1lsbBRaKgmOxqQFQoZBwNJiJBKAA).

Comment: @JarMan This is very intersting. I've also found that "," and "Shift+," also work, but on my instance "Ctrl+," does not---either this is a problem with 6.5 or the shortcut is somehow blocked.

Comment: Tested and it runs ok in 6.4, I have yet to try 6.5

Comment: @JarMan I put a `console.log` on the menus and found they ARE firing, just no shortcut is shown in the menu! Now I'm not sure if that is an issue with Qt passing the shortcut correctly or MacOS Ventura 13.3 (22E252) not rendering the shortcut indicate.

Comment: @jarman Thanks for your review.  Qt Support acknowledges they can reproduce the shortcut working in practice but an error in displaying the shortcut code in the menu itself. They opened https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing, it was found that the shortcuts DO fire but the shortcut code does not appear in the menu. Qt Support has verified and reproduced this and opened a bug at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115642

It is presently considered an bug in the display but not in the shortcut execution.